# SetFocusFilterIntent macOS system extension doesn't run perform() function

Tags: swift, macos, focus, system

I am writing a Focus system extension (sandboxed, Cocoa, entitlements set) for macOS 13/Ventura using Xcode 14.2

I have the extension loading it's UI into the macOS system settings > Focus pane.

so here are the issues:

1. Even though it is loaded, it doesn't seem to ever run the perform() function when the UI is changed by the user or the user invokes Focus > Do Not Disturb.
2. What *can* be done in the perform() function? Like, what is supposed to go there? Nothing seems to work.

```
import AppIntents

struct MacOSFocus: SetFocusFilterIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource {
        return "Focus Settings"
    }
        
    // The description as it appears in the Settings app
    static var description: LocalizedStringResource? = "Focus Settings" // name under Minus icon in options list

    
    // How a configured filter appears on the Focus details screen
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        return DisplayRepresentation(stringLiteral: "Focus Settings") // name under filter once added to Foucs
    }
    
    @Parameter(title: "Show Task Bar", default: false)
    var showDefaultTaskBar: Bool

    @Parameter(title: "Start Timer")
    var startTimer: Bool
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        
        // This doesnt seem to run
        // What can I put here?
        // I need to write string data to a text file somewhere or communicate with the host app in some way.
        
        return .result()
    }
    
}
```

Just trying to get unstuck. Thanks for any help.

Tried adding an NSLog() call in the perform() function for debugging. Even tried using NSSound.beep() just to check that it is getting called. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

After messing a lot with Focus Filter Intent settings in System Settings, while changing the related code in your app, the system stops forwarding Focus Filter events to your app. To get things back to a working situation, simply restart your Mac.